# Regex for commas and periods allowed

Tags: java, regex

I tried searching for an answer to this question and also reading the Regex Wiki but I couldn't find what I'm looking for exactly.

I have a program that validates a document. (It was written by someone else).

If certain lines or characters don't match the regex then an error is generated. I've noted that a few false errors are always generated and I want to correct this. I believe I have narrowed down the problem to this:

Here is an example:

This error is flagged by the program logic:

```
ERROR: File header immediate origin name is invalid: CITIBANK, N.A.
```

Here is the code that causes that error:

```
if(strLine.substring(63,86).matches("[A-Z,a-z,0-9, ]+")){

                                }else{
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: File header immediate origin name is invalid: "+strLine.substring(63,86));
                                    errorFound=true;
                                    fileHeaderErrorFound=true;
                                    bw.write("ERROR: File header immediate origin name is invalid: "+strLine.substring(63,86));
                                    bw.newLine();
```

I believe the reason that the error is called at runtime is because the text contains a period and comma.. I am unsure how to allow these in the regex.

I have tried using this

```
if(strLine.substring(63,86).matches("[A-Z,a-z,0-9,,,. ]+")){
```

and it seemed to work I just wanted to make sure that is the correct way because it doesn't look right.

Comment: @Thomas: No. The only character you have to escape in a character class is `]`. `^` and `-` are the only other two metacharacters that matter, and if you place them correctly, you don't have to escape them, either.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes that's true. As I said I didn't thoroughly read the question so that was a misunderstanding on my side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right in your analysis, the match failed because there was a dot in the text that isn't contained in the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

However, you can simplify the regex - no need to repeat the commas, they don't have any special meaning inside a class:

```
if(strLine.substring(63,86).matches("[A-Za-z0-9,. ]+"))
```

Are you sure that you'll never have to match non-ASCII letters or any other kind of punctuation, though?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm quite certain a period will be the only other punctuation. The files are bank related and have very strict formatting standards. The author of the original probably didn't think about periods though because there are a few as well as commas. Thanks again for your response I can fix my code and remove the triple comma I have.

The author also did the original in beanshell and I moved it to Eclipse so perhaps there are some differences in beanshell. JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Alphabets and digits : a-zA-Z0-9 can effectively be replaced by \w denoting 'words'.
The period and comma don't need escaping and can be used as is. Hence this regex might come in handy:

```
"[\w,.]"
```

Hope this helps. :)